# error: "/opt/stack/logs/error.log: No such file or directory" - devstack deploy in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, openstack, devstack

during the devstack deployment in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, I run the stack.sh script and the error jumps out:

> [Call Trace]
>   ./stack.sh:191:die
>   [ERROR] ./stack.sh:191 If you wish to run this script anyway run with FORCE=yes
>   /home/stack/devstack/functions-common: line 232: /opt/stack/logs/error.log: No such file or directory

someone recommend that I should switch to Ubuntu 14.04 or Ubuntu 16.04, but the server in my lab is way out-of-date(10-year-old), which cannot support higher version of Ubuntu.

So is there a way to solve the problem without the o.s. switch?

Comment: I am seeing same issue with ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 5):

When you try to install DevStack on Linux distribution other then trusty/vivid/wily/7.0/wheezy/sid/testing/jessie/f22/f23/rhel7/kvmibm1. So Ubuntu 12.04 LTS distribution codename name is 'xenial'.
xenial is not in the above list of distribution.
Try this command. This worked for me.

```
$ FORCE=yes ./stack.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the installation and docs for DevStack hasn't changed in some time, you will get this error if you do not create a log directory in your data directory, the docs instruct you to set the user up with a home directory of /opt/stack, the script tries to create a logging destination in that directory and fails then logs this message.

The script has a hammer to skip this portion of the setup:  `FORCE=yes ./stack.sh`

I was just setting up on Fedora 37 and the script exits because it is not tested on this distro so I had to issue the FORCE=yes option.